# animated border on a div

Tags: firefox, css

I tried following code to get an animated border on a div but i am not able to get it on left and right side.here is my code

```
<div id="test">test</div>
#test
{
position:absolute;
width:200px;
top:100px;
left:50px;
-moz-border-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/GziKo.gif)   8 0 stretch;
}
```

here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ahvSR/30/ 
Thanks
**Edit**

Although @Mihalis Bagos solution is good. But i am not interested in wrapper div i want some thing on `test` div or `border-image`

**New Edit**

i have done it using `border-image` now my image is 4x4 pixels before it was 8x8 pixels.Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/5rHCa/

But please can anyone explain thoroughly  why it was not working with 8x8 pixels.

**Final Edit**
It can be done through 8x8 pixel also but no stackoverflow user got the mistake in my fiddle.See my answer.

**Another Final Edit**

The fiddle i have posted using 4x4 and 8x8 http://jsfiddle.net/5rHCa/ and http://jsfiddle.net/LzS7b/ are not working on firefox 3.6 does anyone have idea why these are not working on firefox it is working on chrome though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different AnimGif with transparency in the center;

http://jsfiddle.net/ahvSR/32/

Answer (score 4):

Consider a parent div, which has the animation as the background and the padding you would like the border thickness to be, ie:

```
<div id="wrapper"><div id="test">test</div></div>
#test
{
    background-color: white;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper
{
    width:200px;
    top:100px;
    left:50px;
    position:absolute;
    padding:2px 0px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/GziKo.gif)   top left;
}
```

For cross-browser compatibility. The sample works fine on firefox

Comment: its not working on my firefox plz can you make fiddle and paste link

Comment: Also not working in my firefox (8.0).
Edit: this does though http://jsfiddle.net/ahvSR/7/

Comment: define "not working" please. I explicitly set the padding to be only top and bottom, as this makes sense, but if you change the padding more you will get different results.

Comment: @Hira, just adjust the `padding:2px 0px;` part to your liking if thats what "isn't working"

Comment: @MihalisBagos I took not working to mean the border wasn't showing for the left and right sides, as that is what the original question was asking for.

Comment: @MihalisBagos sorry but now your fiddle is working too i dont know why it was not working before

Comment: @Helen ah right, I misread it, i thought he didn't want it on left and right side, either way this is the solution!

Comment: @MihalisBagos It is a solution, but I'm sure there should be a way to do it with border image even if it is less compatable :)

Comment: i am also looking a border-image solution

Comment: The picture provided is not very sutable with use with this property, read more on: http://css-tricks.com/6883-understanding-border-image/ for the tricks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using CSS3, you can try this method http://jsfiddle.net/ahvSR/31/.
If you need thin borders, then you could make your image thin to the size you need.

Comment: stratulat thanks for your interest. Well your answer does solve the problem but i was also interested that why `border-image` is not working in this case i wanted a clear explanation of why `border-image` is not working in my case. If some answer using `border-image` i will give bounty to him otherwise i will award to you. Thanks very much.

Comment: It does work http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/. I think that probably there's something about your image. Try to apply your code to static .gif or .png file and see how it work. I'm totally believe it's something about image.

Answer (score 1):

Actually all through my in first fiddle i was not using the `border-width` property. So for using `border-image` property i think so `border-width` is necessary.here is my final fiddle with original 8x8 image all those people which were saying about image size it was wrong actually i was missing `border-width`. Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/LzS7b/

Comment: This will work good only, if width and height are multiples of 8, Try `height:28px; width: 204px;`

Comment: @yunzen the fiddle you give will it work for any height and width?

Comment: if or if not will not affect your answer :)

Comment: the background is not from me, it is from http://lorempixel.com. Brilliant effort that! Kudos to them!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are looking at it on Firefox?
I have just added:

```
-webkit-border-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/GziKo.gif)   8 0 stretch;
```

And it works on Chrome.